# ASP.Net WebApi: Invalid URL generated in BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm beginning to use WebApi and I'm having an issue with a URL being incorrectly generated

I have an ApiController like this:

```
public class EntriesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Entry entry)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

And I was trying to create a standard controller (i.e. not webapi) in the same project to test this api (I already tested the api with fiddler and everything is ok there).

I assumed I could use the standard HTML helpers like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "Entries"))
```

However this generates the following markup:

```
<form action="/Entries/Post" method="post">
```

and I expected it to generate

```
<form action="/api/Entries" method="post">
```

What is the correct way to generate the API url from a view?

I am using the default api and controller routes.

Thanks

Comment: Web API should not be used to post html forms, the convention is ajax calls passing JSON objects. My suggestion is to refactor your code and send that post to a normal controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "Entries"))
```

You can not put WebAPI controller and method in MVC BeginForm like above. You need to pass MVC Controller and action to the BeginForm.

You can create a WebAPI EntriesController instance in your MVC controller, then use this instance to call the WebAPI method. See below:

```
//MVC Controller
public class EntriesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Entries()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Entries(SomeModels model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var api = new EntriesController(); // Create WebAPI instance Here
            api.Post(model.entry);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is technically possible by doing:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "api/Entries"))
```

Don't forget, the "Post" value in the `.BeginForm()` extension method doesn't mean anything to an out-of-box Web Api route setup. Only the url and HTTP action matter (and any additional values on the URL for method overloading)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `BeginRouteForm` as link generation to Web API routes always depends on the route name. Also make sure to supply the route value called `httproute` as below.

`@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("DefaultApi", new { controller="Entries", httproute="true" }))`