# How do I generate a webapi url from an MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Based on [How to create ASP.NET Web API Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502306/how-to-create-asp-net-web-api-url)

Neither of these plus a few more combinations of them I've tried are working

```
 <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi",new {area=string.Empty,httproute = string.Empty, controller = "corpuserrequest", action="Get"})">CorpUser</a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Get","CorpUserRequest",new {area=string.Empty,httproute ="", controller = "CorpUserRequest", action="Get"})">CorpUser</a></li>
```

Here's my api config route table:

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407267/multiple-httppost-method-in-mvc4-web-api-controller
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiReq",
            routeTemplate: "webapi/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: null,
           constraints: new { action = "Req" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new
            {
                id = @"^\d*$",// Only integers 
                action = "^(?![rR]eq)$" //anything except req or Req
            }
        );
```

Why isn't the routing working? The RouteUrl returns empty string or null, the Action returns

```
<a href="http://localhost:11601/CorpUserRequest/Get">
```

instead of what the actual url should be `http://localhost:11601/api/CorpUserRequest`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use either of the following to generate links to Web API:

1. `@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new {controller = "corpuserrequest"})`
2. `@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = true, controller = "corpuserrequest"})`

Usually you would use option `1.`, but sometimes you might need to use `2.` like in the following post (this post doesn't necessarily use `RouteUrl`, but the idea is that in places where you do not have a convenient extension like `HttpRouteUrl`, in this case `Html.BeginForm`, you can use `httproute=true` to indicate that you are indeed trying to generate a url to a Web API route)

[ASP.Net WebApi: Invalid URL generated in BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348340/asp-net-webapi-invalid-url-generated-in-beginform/19773898#19773898)