# What's the right way to query my own API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web application that has regular webpages and an API. the regular controllers are in Controllers/, the API controllers are in Controllers/API.

On one of my views I can call

```
$.getJSON("/API/PRAXA/FO")
```

but that only works in development. In production, the application is in a subdirectory, so I would have to call

```
$.getJSON("/DMR/API/PRAXA/FO")
```

How can I determine this properly at run-time, so it works in both development and production?

I tried using

```
@Html.RouteLink("hiddenLink", "DefaultApi", new { action = "FO", controller = "PRAXA" }, new { id = "hiddenLink" })
```

but its `href` attribute is giving me null in both environments.

Comment: use UrlHelper.HttpUrlRoute with the controller, actions and parameters. the helper will generate the full url which will work for both development and production

Comment: @Nkosi that works perfectly, if that was an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`UrlHelper.HttpRouteUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.httprouteurl(v=vs.118).aspx) with the controller, actions and parameters. 
The helper will generate the full URL which will work in both development and production.

```
$.getJSON('@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { action = "FO", controller = "PRAXA" } )')
```

[How do I generate a webapi url from an MVC view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19868321/5233410)